# 'data' function not hit in seemingly successful jquery post

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post

Why the following jquery .post success function isn't working or how I can check to see why it isn't working:

```
    $('#delete_visit').click(function(){
    var vg_id = $("#id_visit_select").val();//select visit from a dropdown
    $.post('{% url 'study.views.delete_visit' %}', 
    //posting to django view, this seems to work
    { v_id: v_id  },
    function(data){
    if (data){
    alert('data posted');
    //not hit, even though seems like django view succesfully deletes visit
    }
    else{
    alert('data post failure');
    //also not hit
    }
    }
    );//end post
    });//end click
```

Django view:

```
    def delete_visit(request):
        v_id=request.POST['v_id']
        if v_id:
            v_obj=Visit.objects.get(id=v_id)
            print v_obj.id, 'it works!' # this all prints
            v_obj.delete()
        return HttpResponse('a')
```

---

#### Solved

I found out the issue - it's pretty stupid on my part. My click target was an href link with '#' and because I didn't have a preventDefault in my click function, it was refreshing before the data post and I was getting an Error Code 10054: Connection reset

Comment: In general, I would like to know a better way to debug these ajax posts other than just leaving alert landmines everywhere

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue - it's pretty stupid on my part. My click target was an href link with '#' and because I didn't have a preventDefault in my click function, it was refreshing before the data post and I was getting an Error Code 10054: Connection reset

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of tools to help debug these types of situations.

If I were going to start debugging this issue, I would first look into any error logs that may exist on your server and see if any Exceptions are being raised.  If all looks well there, I would use a tool called 'pdb' (https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) and insert a break point at the start of the view and step through each line of code to verify all if working correctly...

```
def delete_visit(request):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        v_id=request.POST['v_id']
        if v_id:
            v_obj=Visit.objects.get(id=v_id)
            print v_obj.id, 'it works!' # this all prints
            v_obj.delete()
        return HttpResponse('a')
```

If all checks out well there, then it's time to review the client side code and see what is going on there.  Most modern browsers come with consoles to inspect and monitor all network requests and javascript code.  I would start by taking a look at the logged network requests and see what your ajax request is actually returning.  It may be returning a non success code such as 500 or 404.  If this is the case then the jQuery callback function in which you have for the $.post function won't be called because that is only executed upon a successful response.

In regards to if there is a better way to debug ajax, try inserting the statement 'debugger;' or placing a breakpoint within your browsers development tools in order to step though executing just like the way pdb does.

Comment: Thank you. I have been using firebug, my boss pointed out that it might be better to use a newer version and he was right. Also, he tipped me off on firefox>developer>browser console. THIS IS REALLY USEFUL for debugging js

Comment: Yes hence the line 'Most modern browsers come with consoles to inspect and monitor all network requests and javascript code.' :)  Glad you are figuring it out though!